# After installation of phpmyadmin on ubuntu I forgot the username and password of phpmyadmin. How will I able to recover these again?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

after installation of phpmyadmin on Ubuntu I forgot the **username and password** of          phpmyadmin. How will I able to recover these again?

Answer (score 0):

Since phpMyAdmin just authenticates against MySQL, you've actually lost your *MySQL* credentials. Fortunately, it's easy to reset.

`dpkg-reconfigure -plow mysql-server-5.5` or of course whatever package is installed instead (for instance, `mysql-server-5.1`). If you're not sure, you can check with `dpkg -l mysql-server* | grep ^ii`.

The username is root.